# Numbers appearing in table of contents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

The numbers at the left of the heading have suddenly appeared in the TOC.

Also, some of the haedings are at the right hand side (2.3 - 2.6), whereas from 2.7 onwards is displayed correctly at the left side.

```
2.  The Board   8
2.1 Composition of Board    8
(7) 2.3 Conditions of membership    9
(8) 2.4 Casual vacancies    9
(9) 2.5 Allowances and expenses 10
(10)    2.6 Validity of acts    10
(11)    2.7     Registrars of Board 10
(12)    2.8     Staff of Board  10
(13)    2.9     Functions of Board  11
(14)    2.10    Committees  11
```

Can you advise how to correct?

Answer (score 0):

From memory if you directly add list formatting to a paragraph then the numbering will appear in the TOC. If you add the list formatting to the style which is applied to the paragraph then the numbering does not appear. Hopefully that helps.

Regarding the alignment, could you clarify what's incorrect?